# Large file upload issue

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload  upto 10GB files using a normal php form. But after increasing the below values,

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
php_value upload_max_filesize
php_value post_max_size
request_terminate_timeout
FcgidMaxRequestLen
```

I can upload a file upto 3GB without any problem. But when it goes beyond that there is an timeout issue when transferring the files from local server to the CDN am using. I also use progress bar to indicate the upload process which stops when a timeout issue happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can set time limit like this :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);//unlimited
```

Not recommended to set to unlimited but you can try it and once you have a good estimate about the time you adjust it.

---

## [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>  **`set_time_limit`** — Limits the maximum execution time

Comment: Hi Meda, Thank you for your answers I will definitely try this, but another doubt I have is I placed the code in the top of the page where i have the form, is that the right place to write the code.

Comment: I tried using the above function but it is not working. Am getting an error as UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL when uploading large size files, so referring to a link in stack i found that I need to add header("Connection: close");, but am not sure of where the line should be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can try IaaS solutions instead.

For example, our service [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) - supports uploading files up to 5GB, and the uploaded files are available on CDN instantly. If the size limit is too low, we can increase it for you.